# Como meter 3 etiquetas dentro de un div en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero mandar los 3 id con su texto a un div, todo en la misma función.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("empresa").innerHTML = nombre;
document.getElementById("ubicacion").innerHTML = ciudad;
document.getElementById("experiencia").innerHTML = edad;

<!-- ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr,las 3 id van a caja -->
document.getElementById("caja").innerHTML = empresa + ubicacion + edad;
</script>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Si agregaste la etiqueta de jquery, es porque lo estas utilizando (podrias utilizar) o me equivoco.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con `JQuery` con la función `.attr()` y `.text()` , te dejo un ejemplo;

```js
$( "#caja" ).text($('#empresa').attr('id') + $( "#empresa" ).text() + $('#ubicacion').attr('id') + $( "#ubicacion" ).text() + $('#experiencia').attr('id') + $( "#experiencia" ).text());


console.log($('#caja').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="empresa">Contenido empresa</div>
<div id="ubicacion">Contenido ubicacion</div>
<div id="experiencia">Contenido experiencia</div>

<div id="caja"></div>
```

Lo que se está realizando en el código es que se hace referencia al `div` con el `id = "caja"` y a ese `div` le agrega el `id` + `texto` de cada uno de los otros `divs` concatenándolos.

Te dejo la documentación por si la necesitas:

--Se utiliza para obtener `texto`:
http://api.jquery.com/text/

--Se utiliza para obtener valor de `id`:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Espero te ayude. Saludos.